# How to check the execution state of “scheduledJob”?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, dolphindb

How to check the execution state of “scheduledJob”?
How to check whether the function “scheduledJob” execute completely or not?

Answer (score 1):

1. See how scheduleJob is defined

```py
getScheduledJobs()
```

| userId | jobId | jobDesc | startDate | endDate | frequency | scheduleTime | days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| admin | daily000 | Daily Job 1 | 2021.09.27 | 2021.09.27 | 'D' | 12:03m 13:08m |  |
| admin | daily | Daily Job 1 | 2021.09.27 | 2021.09.27 | 'D' | 12:53m 13:58m |  |

2. View the completed scheduleJob

```py
select * from getRecentJobs() where jobDesc like "%Daily%" order by startTime desc
```

| node | userID | jobId | jobDesc | priority | parallelism | receivedTime | startTime | endTime | errorMsg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| local8848 | admin | daily000 | Daily Job 1 | 8 | 64 | 2021.09.27T12:03:06.784 | 2021.09.27T12:03:06.785 | 2021.09.27T12:03:06.785 |  |

3. getJobMessage and getJobReturn to view the running log and return value of each job

The running log is saved in the jodId.msg file, and the return value of the scheduled job is saved in the jobId.object file. These files are saved in the directory /batchJobs